# Creating a Pandas DataFrame from a Dictionary of different-length list of Tuples

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary of format:
Keys = Person's name
Items = list(Tuple(GUID, INT(value)), ...)

`{'Person A':[('abc123',1),('bcc222',2),('igh643',1)],'Person B': [('abc123',4)],'Person C': [('abc123',2),('icy558',7)]}`

and I would like to turn this into a pandas dataframe of the format Index: GUID, Columns: Person's Name, values: INT(value).  This should look something like:

[image: Desired Dataframe]

I have tried:

`pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items()]))`

but it results in:

[image: unwanted results dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just further flatten the tupled values so the resulting table can be pivoted easily.

### Code

`dic` is the given dict data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[k, v[0], v[1]] for k, ls_v in dic.items() for v in ls_v],
    columns=["Person", "GUID", "value"]
).pivot(index="GUID", columns="Person")

# drop hierarchical level of "value"
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

### Result

```
print(df)

Person Person A Person B Person C
GUID                             
abc123      1.0      4.0      2.0
bcc222      2.0      NaN      NaN
icy558      NaN      NaN      7.0
igh643      1.0      NaN      NaN
```